# Getting error while writing test cases for angular service AppConfig.settings.serviceUrl is undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, web-frontend

**myservice.ts //ts file**

** getting AppConfig.settings.serviceUrl as undefined not 
    getting how to make the mock of it and Appconfig is class and setting 
   is variable where `serviceURL` is "http://localhost/4200/"**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
export class Sendnotificationservice {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public sendnotification(
    notificationModel: SendnotificationToModel
  ): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(
      AppConfig.settings.serviceUrl +
        'api/Sendnotificationservice/sendnotification',
      notificationModel
      //AppConfig.setting.serviceUrl getting undefined error is here
    );
  }
}
```

My test

```
describe('Sendnotificationservice', () => {
  let service: Sendnotificationservice;
  let httpSpy: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpclientTestingModule],
      providers: [Sendnotificationservice],
    });
    service = TestBed.get(Sendnotificationservice);
    service = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });
  it('it should get mail', () => {
    const test = {
      clientno: '',
      firstName: 'dev',
      lastName: 'som',
      phoneNo: '484758373',
    };
    service.sendnotification(test).subscribe((data) => {
      expect(data).toEqual(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Show how `AppConfig` is `imported` and used into your service, so we can suggest how to mock it.

Comment: import {AppConfig} from "src/app/global/config/app-config"
inservice it is used like:
return this.http.post<any>(
      AppConfig.settings.serviceUrl +
        'api/Sendnotificationservice/sendnotification',
      notificationModel

Comment: Can you show an example of the content of the file `src/app/global/config/app-config.ts`? Also, I'm noticing that your example code has an issue with the variable `service`. You are assigning to it twice. Is that a typo in your example, is it?

Comment: import { IAppConfig } from "./app-config.model";
import { environment } from"src/environments/environment";
@Injectable()
export classAppConfig
 {static settings: iAppConfig;constructor(privatehttp:HttpClient) 
{}
load()
 {
const jsonFile window.location.hostname.toLowerCase().indexof("localhost") !== -1
? 'assets/config/config.local.json'  'assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json';
 
return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise() .them((response: Response) =>{
AppConfig.settings = <any>response;resolve();})
;})
;}}

Comment: service is the typo in example